# Return the Array of Bytes from FileReader()

Tags: javascript, filereader

I need some help returning the "bytes" variable from this function below to be used as input in another function.

```
function openfile() {
var input = document.getElementById("files").files;
var fileData = new Blob([input[0]]);

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileData);
reader.onload = function(){
    var arrayBuffer = reader.result
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    console.log(bytes);
}
```

I'd like to get the return of the above function and use the array of bytes as input parameter in another function.

Comment: How about `return bytes;`? To use it as a parameter for another function, use it like this: `myfunction(openfile(evt));`

Comment: I get "undefined" if changing from "console.log(bytes);" to "return bytes;" and calling outside "console.log(openfile());"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use promises to wait for the file reader to finish loading your file.

> The **Promise** object is used for deferred and asynchronous computations. A Promise represents an operation that hasn't completed yet, but is expected to in the future.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) you can find more information on promises.

Here is an example on how you could integrate a promise into your situation.

```js
(function (document) {
  var input = document.getElementById("files"),
      output = document.getElementById('output');

  // Eventhandler for file input. 
  function openfile(evt) {
    var files = input.files;
    // Pass the file to the blob, not the input[0].
    fileData = new Blob([files[0]]);
    // Pass getBuffer to promise.
    var promise = new Promise(getBuffer(fileData));
    // Wait for promise to be resolved, or log error.
    promise.then(function(data) {
      // Here you can pass the bytes to another function.
      output.innerHTML = data.toString();
      console.log(data);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Error: ',err);
    });
  }

  /* 
    Create a function which will be passed to the promise
    and resolve it when FileReader has finished loading the file.
  */
  function getBuffer(fileData) {
   return function(resolve) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileData);
        reader.onload = function() {
          var arrayBuffer = reader.result
          var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
          resolve(bytes);
        }
    }
  }
  
    // Eventlistener for file input.
  input.addEventListener('change', openfile, false);
}(document));
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. But I think I'll change the way I was planning to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Note that IE didn't support Promise objects until version 11.

Comment: Look nice but does not work for me. Line var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer); has an error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayBuffer | SharedArrayBuffer | ArrayLike<number>'.

Comment: @mli Hi, may I ask, are you using TypeScript? If so, are you sure that you are correctly casting your types?

Comment: @DavidDomain. Yea, it's typescript. So I was forced to put it like this: const bytes = new Uint8Array(reader.result as ArrayBuffer);  Thanks anyway, I'm just newbie, so I thought there is no difference between javascript and typescript.

Answer (score 4):

If you pass the `onload` function the event, you can make it work.

```
reader.onload = function(e){
    var arrayBuffer = e.target.result;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    console.log(bytes);
}
```

This corrects it from `reader.result` to `e.target.result;`.

Additionally, there's a problem in using `fileData`, which is set to `Blob[files[0]]` and sending that to `reader.readAsArrayBuffer`.  Remove `fileData` and call it with `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(input[0]);`, instead.

Comment: e.target has no result property.

Comment: @KingWilder If you're using IE, you might need `e.srcElement` instead. It's there if you're using Chrome. But also something that was likely making it not work, the OP is basically using `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(new Blob([input[0]]));` when it should've been `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(document.getElementById("files").files[0]);`, which didn't originally get addressed, here, and will alter what `e` is.  I added it in an edit.