# Convert input type = file to array of bytes - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible convert input type = file in HTML 5 to array of bytes in Javascript?
I read a few articles about that but the solutions provided don't work for me.
I tried these:
[Getting byte array through input type = file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556664/getting-byte-array-through-input-type-file), 
[Return the Array of Bytes from FileReader()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433413/return-the-array-of-bytes-from-filereader?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I need it for my ajax post method. In ASP.NET MVC app I have ViewModel with field type of byte[] and I want to write this array to database.

Code in question:

```
<input type="file" id="Receipt" />
```

POST method:

```
$(function () {
            $("#btnregister").click(function () {     
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AddUser",
                    data: 
                        {
                            File: (?)
                        }
                });
            });
        });
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<input type="file" id="Receipt" />` ?

Comment: Yes my fault but that's not it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting byte array through input type = file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556664/getting-byte-array-through-input-type-file)

Comment: No, it's not working